# Can a male cat look like he isn't neutered when he is?

Tags: cats, desexing

I recently adopted a pair of cats from a shelter, male and female. I was told that they were neutered and spayed, but the male appears to have normal testicles. I'm taking the cats to my own vet for a checkup and will ask about it then. (They are indoor cats and the female is definitely spayed, so it's not an emergency.)

Is it normal for a neutered male cat to appear to have normal testicles? I had difficulty finding the answer on the Internet, and thought others might be interested in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, but if you have any concerns, check with your vet.

I took the cats to my own vet for a checkup. By palpating his testicles she confirmed that Professor Paws is indeed neutered. She was also surprised at his appearance, but suggested that he had an especially large pair before neutering. He is a very confident cat ;)

Answer (score -1):

Some males, especially big toms neutered as adults, can still look like they have testicles (it tends to actually be just tufted hair on the scrotum).  If there is ever any question, a vet can look at his penis: unneutered males will have little barbs on the penis, which are absent in neutered males.  This is most useful for identifying cryptorchid cats (in which the testicles don't descend and instead remain out of sight up in the abdomen).

Comment: I have not heard of penis barbs being impacted by neutering, can you add a reference for that?